# Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; In MessageListener

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms, message-listener

Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

I am getting the above error when i am injecting a spring dependency and using it inside MessageListener bean

Answer (score 0):

Request scope is only available on web (HTTP) request threads not on JMS listener container threads.

Your dependency seems to be tightly coupled to the web layer and is not designed to be called using JMS.